# Rewrite subdomain url like bigcommerce.com

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

i have 2 folder **a** and **b**

I want to rewrite url as like subdomain style.

**domain.com/a => a.domain.com** => *it will run folder a*

**domain.com/b => b.domain.com** => *it will run folder b*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the folders `a` and `b` are at the root of your domain, try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([ab])\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for `.htaccess` files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is even installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for `.htaccess` files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: thanks for your commenting but it doesn't work, it makes 500 internal server error

Comment: Are you sure mod-rewrite is installed? (See instructions in the answer.)

Comment: i'm sure, i found your mistake, there was a space between  ^ and % at last row. i removed it. it ran but incorrect, it wasn't run into folder a or b when i typed a.domain.com. it ran index.php at root

Comment: `there was a space between ^ and % ` No, that space is correct.

Comment: it made 500 internal server error. i did't know why

Comment: I use this code

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.abc\.de$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^((?!(.*)/).*)$ /%1/$1 [L,NC]`